# In Java, How do I capitalize the first letters of an automated input?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the auto grader/compiler for my assignment to give me points for the exact match required for the automated input. Here is my output:
Enter playlist's title: DANCE LIST PLAYLIST MENU

Here is the expected output: 
Enter playlist's title: Dance List PLAYLIST MENU

Here are my code pages. I do got some other issues in this code when submitted to ZyBooks also. I can post them later. Thank you for any help.

```
public class SongEntry {

   private String uniqueID;

   private String songName;

   private String artistName;

   private int songLength;

   SongEntry nextNode;

   SongEntry() {

       uniqueID = "";

       songName = "";

       artistName = "";

       songLength = 0;

       nextNode = null;

   }

   SongEntry(String uniqueID, String songName, String artistName, int songLength) {

       this.uniqueID = uniqueID;

       this.songName = songName;

       this.songLength = songLength;

       this.artistName = artistName;

       this.nextNode = null;

   }

   public void insertAfter(SongEntry entry) {

       SongEntry entries = this;

       while (entries.nextNode != null) {

           entries = entries.nextNode;

       }

       entries.nextNode = entry;

   }

   public void setNext(SongEntry entry) {

       this.nextNode = entry;

   }

   public String getID() {

       return this.uniqueID;

   }

   public String getSongName() {

       return this.songName;

   }

   public String getArtistName() {

       return this.artistName;

   }

   public int getSongLength() {

       return this.songLength;

   }

   public SongEntry getNext() {

       return this.nextNode;

   }

   public void printPlaylistSongs() {

       System.out.println("Unique ID: " + getID());

       System.out.println("Song Name: " + getSongName());

       System.out.println("Artist Name: " + getArtistName());

       System.out.println("Song Length(in seconds): " + getSongLength());

   }

   public void setSongName(String songName2) {

       this.songName = songName2;

   }

   public void setUniqueID(String id) {

       this.uniqueID = id;

   }

   public void setArtistName(String artistName2) {

       this.artistName = artistName2;

   }

   public void setSongLength(int songLength2) {

       this.songLength = songLength2;

   }

}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Playlist {

   public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static Scanner scInt = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static SongEntry headSong = new SongEntry();

   public static SongEntry tailSong = new SongEntry();

   public static SongEntry allEntries;

   public static int numberOfNodes = 0;

   public static void printMenu(String playlistTitle)

   {

   System.out.println("\n"+playlistTitle.toUpperCase()+" PLAYLIST MENU");

   System.out.println("a - Add song\nd - Remove song\nc - Change position of song\ns - Output songs by specific artist");

   System.out.println("t - Output total time of playlist (in seconds)\no - Output full playlist\nq - Quit");

   System.out.println("\nChoose an option:");

   String option = sc.next();

   boolean isEnter = option.equals("a") || option.equals("d") || option.equals("c") || option.equals("s") || option.equals("t") || option.equals("o") || option.equals("q");

   if(isEnter)

   {

   switch(option.charAt(0))

   {

   case 'a': addSong();

   printMenu(playlistTitle);

   break;

   case 'd': allEntries = removeSong(allEntries);

   printMenu(playlistTitle);

   break;

   case 'c': allEntries = changeSongPosition(allEntries);

   printMenu(playlistTitle);

   break;

   case 's': songsBySpecificArtist(allEntries);

   printMenu(playlistTitle);

   break;

   case 't': totalTimeofPlaylist(allEntries);

   printMenu(playlistTitle);

   break;

   case 'o': outputFullPlaylist(allEntries);

   printMenu(playlistTitle);

   break;

   case 'q': break;

   }

   }

   else

   {

   System.out.println("Invalid Choice !");

   printMenu(playlistTitle);

   }

   }

   public static void outputFullPlaylist(SongEntry entries)

   {

   int counter = 1;

   if(entries != null)

   {

   System.out.println(counter+".");

   entries.printPlaylistSongs(); // head node

   counter++;

   while(entries.nextNode != null) // all the remaining nodes

   {

   entries = entries.nextNode;

   System.out.println(counter+".");

   entries.printPlaylistSongs();

   counter++;

   }

   }

   else

   {

       System.out.println("Playlist is empty");

   }

   }

   public static void addSong()

   {

   sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("ADD SONG");

   System.out.println("Enter song's Unique ID: ");

   String songID = sc.next();

   sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter song's name: ");

   String songname = sc.nextLine();

   sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter artist's name: ");

   String artistName = sc.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Enter song's length(in seconds): ");

   int songlength = scInt.nextInt();

   SongEntry entry = new SongEntry(songID, songname, artistName, songlength);

   if(allEntries == null)

   {

   headSong = entry; // this is the head

   allEntries = entry;

   tailSong = entry; // this is the tail

   numberOfNodes++;

   }

   else

   {

       allEntries.insertAfter(entry);

   tailSong = entry;

   numberOfNodes++;

   }

   }

   public static SongEntry removeSong(SongEntry entries)

   {

   System.out.println("Enter the song's unique ID: ");

   String id = sc.next();

   SongEntry newEntry = null, entry=null;

   int counter = 0;

   while(entries != null)

   {

       if(counter!=0)

       {

           newEntry.nextNode = null;

           newEntry = newEntry.nextNode;

       }

       if(!entries.getID().equals(id))

       {

           newEntry = new SongEntry();

           newEntry.setUniqueID(entries.getID());

           newEntry.setSongName(entries.getSongName());

           newEntry.setArtistName(entries.getArtistName());

           newEntry.setSongLength(entries.getSongLength());

           if(entry == null)

               entry = newEntry;

           else

               entry.insertAfter(newEntry);

           counter++;

       }

       else

       {

           System.out.println(entries.getSongName()+" removed");

           numberOfNodes--;

       }

       entries = entries.nextNode;

   }

   return entry;

   }

   public static SongEntry changeSongPosition(SongEntry entries)

   {

   System.out.println("CHANGE POSITION OF SONG");

   System.out.println("ENTER song's current position: ");

   int currentPos = scInt.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Enter new position of song: ");

   int newPos = scInt.nextInt();

   SongEntry currentPosEntry = null, entry = null, newPosEntry = null, returnEntry = null;

   entry = entries;

   int counter = 1;

// System.out.println("Number of nodes: " + numberOfNodes);

   if(newPos<1)

       newPos = 1;

   else if(newPos>numberOfNodes)

       newPos = numberOfNodes;

   System.out.println("cuurent pos: "+currentPos);

   System.out.println("new pos: "+newPos);

   for(int i=1; i<=numberOfNodes; i++)

   {

      if(i==currentPos)

       currentPosEntry = entries;

      else if(i==newPos)

          newPosEntry = entries;

      else

          entries = entries.nextNode;

   }

// System.out.println("After for loop");

   //System.out.println("Current song details" ); currentPosEntry.printPlaylistSongs();

// System.out.println("New song details"); newPosEntry.printPlaylistSongs();

   entries = entry;

   while(counter <= numberOfNodes+1)

   {

       if(counter == currentPos) // we need to adjust the current position

       {

           entries = entries.nextNode;

           if(entries !=null)

           {

           entry = new SongEntry(entries.getID(), entries.getSongName(), entries.getArtistName(), entries.getSongLength());

           if(returnEntry == null)

               returnEntry = entry;

           else

               returnEntry.insertAfter(entry);

           entries = entries.nextNode;

           }

           counter++;

       }

       else if(counter == newPos)

       {

           entry = currentPosEntry;

           entry.nextNode = null;

           if(returnEntry == null)

               returnEntry = entry;

           else

               returnEntry.insertAfter(entry);

           counter++;

       }

       else

       {

           if(entries !=null)

           {

           entry = new SongEntry(entries.getID(), entries.getSongName(), entries.getArtistName(), entries.getSongLength());

           if(returnEntry == null)

               returnEntry = entry;

           else

               returnEntry.insertAfter(entry);

           entries = entries.nextNode;

           }

           counter++;

       }

   }

return returnEntry;

   }

   public static void totalTimeofPlaylist(SongEntry entries)

   {

   System.out.println("OUTPUT TOTAL TIME OF PLAYLIST (IN SECONDS)");

   int totalSeconds = entries.getSongLength();

   entries = entries.nextNode;

   while(entries != null)

   {

   totalSeconds += entries.getSongLength();

   entries = entries.nextNode;

   }

   System.out.println("Total Time: "+totalSeconds+" seconds");

   }

   public static void songsBySpecificArtist(SongEntry entries)

   {

   sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("OUTPUT SONGS BY SPECIFIC ARTIST");

   System.out.println("Enter artist's name: ");

   String artistname = sc.nextLine();

   while(entries != null)

   {

   if(entries.getArtistName().equals(artistname))

   {

   entries.printPlaylistSongs();

   }

   entries = entries.nextNode;

   }

   }

   /**

   * @param args

   */

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   System.out.println("Enter playlist's title:");

   sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   String title = sc.nextLine();

   printMenu(title);

   }

}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to do this yourself yet? I'm afraid your code is far too long for us to read through and try to guess what you want. It's best to strip your code down to a simple example that demonstrates the problem you're having. You can read the help section on how to create a [mcve] for help with that.

Comment: That being said, there **is** a third-party library that can help with capitalizing the first letter or a `String`'s words: the [Apache Commons Text](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) library and its [WordUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html) class.

Comment: I did try, but the steps I took all gave me results I did not want. I apologize for the long code. I am a newby and am not sure what to provide. I will check out the links you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with toUppperCase() which capitalizes the entire string.

```
public static String capitalizeWord(String str){  
    String words[]=str.split("\\s");  
    String capitalizeWord="";  
    for(String w:words){  
        String first=w.substring(0,1);  
        String afterfirst=w.substring(1);  
        capitalizeWord+=first.toUpperCase()+afterfirst+" ";  
    }  
    return capitalizeWord.trim();  
}
```

To print you would do:

```
//to ensure all other letters are lowercase
playlistTitle.toLowerCase();
//to capitalize first letters
System.out.println("\n"+ capitalizeWord(playlistTitle) +" PLAYLIST MENU");
```

*capitalizeWord() found at https://www.javatpoint.com/java-program-to-capitalize-each-word-in-string*